# dplyr Find records that have specifc set of values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, specification-pattern

I have a dataset that has some ID and associated timepoints. I want to filter out IDs that have a specific combination of timepoints. If I filter using %in% or |, I get IDs out of the specific combination. How do I do this in R ?

| ID | Timepoint |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 12 |

I want to filter IDs that have timepoints 1,6 and 12 and exclude other IDs.

Result would be IDs 1,3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                 Timepoint = c(1, 6, 12, 1, 1, 6, 12, 18, 1, 6, 12))

df %>%
  filter(Timepoint %in% c(1, 6, 12)) %>%
  mutate(indicator = 1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Timepoint = c(1, 6, 12)) %>%
  filter(!ID %in% pull(filter(., is.na(indicator)), ID)) %>%
  select(indicator)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID indicator
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1         1
2     1         1
3     1         1
4     3         1
5     3         1
6     3         1
7     4         1
8     4         1
9     4         1
```

Comment: Hi, I want IDs which have all three of the timepoints (1,6 and 12). In this case the result should be only 1,3 and 4 as ID 2 has only Timepoint1.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    filter(all(c(1, 6, 12) %in% Timepoint)) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID Timepoint
   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1         1
 2     1         6
 3     1        12
 4     3         1
 5     3         6
 6     3        12
 7     3        18
 8     4         1
 9     4         6
10     4        12
```

Comment: Hi, I want IDs which have all three of the timepoints (1,6 and 12). In this case the result should be only 1,3 and 4 as ID 2 has only Timepoint1.

Answer (score -1):

From your data, ID 2 has time point 1. So if filter by time points 1, 6, 12, the result will be 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 1, 3, 4.

```
ids <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
time_points <- c(1, 6, 12, 1, 1, 6, 12, 18, 1, 6, 12)
dat <- data.frame(ids, time_points)
unique(dat$ids[dat$time_points %in% c(1, 6, 12)])
```